# Funcionamiento de form al cambiarlo de input a select

Tags: jquery, html, select, entrada

En un formulario de envío de datos de contacto tenía previamente un `input` en el que el usuario ingresaba su país. Ahora tuve que cambiar el `input` por un `select`, para que el usuario elija el país de una lista.

Estéticamente funciona todo bien, pero lo que no funciona es el envío del formulario.

HTML

```
<label>
                            <select name="country" id="country" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>País</option>
                                <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                                <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia </option>
                                <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                                <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                                <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                                <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                                <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                                <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                                <option value="Guayana Francesa">Guayana Francesa</option>
                                <option value="Granada">Granada</option>
                                <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                                <option value="Guayana">Guayana</option>
                                <option value="Haití">Haití</option>
                                <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                                <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                                <option value="México">México</option>
                                <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                                <option value="Panamá">Panamá</option>
                                <option value="Perú">Perú</option>
                                <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                                <option value="República Dominicana">República Dominicana</option>
                                <option value="Surinam">Surinam</option>
                                <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                                <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            country: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            repeatEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
      terms: {
        required: true
      }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            //event.preventDefault();
            $('#submit').addClass('disabled').text('Enviando');
            $.ajax({
                url: '../services/form.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    $('.message').html('Te suscribiste correctamente').addClass('success');
          $('#submit').text('Enviado');
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('.message').html('Hubo un error en el envío').addClass('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: `pero lo que no funciona es el envío del formulario.`¿El que no funciona? ¿Te da algún error? Enfoca un poco más cual es tu problema para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: El formulario tiene dos mensajes: en caso de envío correcto, envía el mensaje "Te suscribiste correctamente", y si no funciona, "Hubo un error en el envío". Por el momento con todo lo que probé sólo me apareció el mensaje de error, y a veces solamente la página se refresca.

Comment: Creo que estás usando el plugin de JQuery validate por lo que puede que esta pregunta te sea de utilidad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901125/jquery-validate-required-select. Parece ser que para validar que un `select` sea `required` necesitas hacerlo de manera especial.

Comment: @TheWoodStudio creo que nos ayudaría más ver el log de errores que genera. Oh si revisas la ejecución paso por paso y detallas que función te genera problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que tu error se debe a tu validación, el atributo minlength, puede estar haciéndote estragos, solo en el select:

```
country: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
 },
```

Lo Correcto Seria:

```
country: {
  required: true 
},
```

El atributo minlength debería usarse solo en input's.